# Poor matrix reconstruction from eigenvectors in python vs R

Tags: python, r, eigenvalue, eigenvector, laplacian

I am trying to learn python, and I have run into something confusing to me. Just as a sanity check, I wanted to make sure I could reconstruct a graph laplacian matrix from its eigenvectors and eigenvalues. In R this works as expected, but not in python. The python reconstructed matrix is pretty far off - the norm(Laplacian - estimate) ~ 0.99, while in R it is ~1e-16. I was hoping that someone could explain to me what is going on here. I've posted the code for both languages below:

In R:

```
library(igraph)
g <- watts.strogatz.game(1, 20, 3, 0, loops = FALSE, multiple = FALSE)
A <- as.matrix(as_adjacency_matrix(g, type = c("both"),
                                   attr = NULL, edges = FALSE, names = TRUE,
                                   sparse = FALSE))
A <- -A
diag(A) <- abs(rowSums(A))
D <- diag(diag(A)^-0.5, dmn[1])
Ln <- D %*% A %*% D
eL <- eigen(Ln)
rL <- eL$vectors %*% diag(eL$values) %*% t(eL$vectors)
print(norm(Ln - rL))
```

In Python:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

n=20
G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(n, 3, 0) 
L = nx.normalized_laplacian_matrix(G).toarray()
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(L)
idx = evals.argsort()[::-1]   
evals = evals[idx]
F = evecs[:,idx]
D = np.diag(evals)
FDF = np.linalg.multi_dot([F, D, F.T])
rec = np.linalg.norm(L - FDF)
print(rec)
```

Thank you!

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not really answer the question, but using `np.linalg.svd` instead of `np.linalg.eig` does seem to work fine.

**edit** actually, now I understand. `numpy` has `linalg.eig` which does **not** assume that the matrix is symmetric (or hermitian) and `linalg.eigh` (which does). Use the second, and all is well.

Comment: Got it. I know that with R there are two functions for PCA, one of which uses eigen of the covariance matrix while the other just does SVD. The latter is preferred for numerical accuracy but still doesn't explain this kind of disparity. Thanks though!

Comment: @user8271479 I completely agree. When I try it I get a much lower (though still unacceptable, around 0.08) discrepancy with eig.

Comment: @user8271479 See the edit. R must check whether the matrix is symmetric, and then use the more stable/faster algorithm, but with python you have to do it by hand as in the answer.